# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm using Flutter Web. [Firebase 7.3.0 plugin](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/firebase). 
And the Firebase SDK version 7.15.0 (have tried to downgrade to 7.14.6 without success.). 
And moreover, it is hosted in Firebase hosting so there should NOT be any connection problem between Firebase Hosting and Firestore.

Then the error information from the browser's console is:

> Firestore (7.15.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: getToken aborted due to token change.
>   This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I also have tried to use both
    `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/` and `/__/firebase/7.15.0/` for the SDK url and both didn't work.

And please note that the site is working (can connect to Firestore) when running from Android Studio locally + Chrome.

Did I missed any settings between Firebase Hosting and Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your `applicationId` in app/build.gradle file matches the `package_name` in google-services.json